# Add a point to scale legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple set of points to place in a scatterplot in R. One set of points is training data, the other is a single point of test data. I make a scatterplot of the training data, and add the test data point to the same plot, all using `ggplot2()`. I wish to add the test data point to the same legend already defined for the training data.

Firstly, some data for those who want to play along.

```
A1 <- c(0,0)
A2 <- c(1,1)
A3 <- c(2,2)
B1 <- c(6,6)
B2 <- c(5.5,7)
B3 <- c(6.5,5)
train1 <- data.frame(rbind(A1,A2,A3, B1,B2,B3))
names(train1) <- c("X", "Y")
test_point <- data.frame("X" = 4.0, "Y" = 4.0) # make the test point a df to place nicely with ggplot.
cl <- factor(c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3))) # class labels
```

Now let's make a scatterplot of the train and test data:

```
ggplot(data = train1) +
    aes(X, Y, colour = cl) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    geom_point(data = test_point, aes(X, Y), colour = "NavyBlue", size = 4) +
    labs(size= "1", x = "X coords", y = "Y coords",
         title = "Features for KNN", vjust=-10,
         colour = "Class Labels") +  # change the label for legend by variable name in aes()
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, vjust=1),
          axis.title=element_text(size=16), 
          legend.position="bottom", legend.direction = "vertical", #change location and direction of legend
          legend.text = element_text(colour="blue", size = 16, face = "bold")) +  #change style for legend text
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18))
```

which makes a decent enough plot, but doesn't have anything in the legend for the **NavyBlue test_point**.

[image: Scatterplot with nothing in legend for test-point]

Anyone know how to add the `test_point` to the legend output? I have gotten it to represent, but not nicely, via changing the first `geom_point` to

```
    geom_point(data = test_point, aes(X, Y, colour = "Test Data"), size = 4) +
```

which yields this without `NavyBlue` being specified. So how to keep the Navy Blue coloring with this formulation?

[image: Legend has color name as name]

Naively, one might try

```
geom_point(data = test_point, aes(X, Y, colour = "Test Data"), colour = "NavyBlue", size = 4) +
```

but that results in the first plot, i.e., the additional legend entry goes away.

EDIT: To be clear, I'm trying to do this with a separate `geom_point()`. I wish to be able to add a separate value to the scale legend without merging that new data with the other data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the only reason you're using multiple layers is for the sizes, which seems unnecessary to me.

```
new_df <- rbind(train1, test_point)
new_df$size <- c(rep(3,6), 4)
new_df$cl <- c(rep("red", 3), rep("green", 3), "NavyBlue")

ggplot(new_df, aes(X,Y, colour= cl)) + geom_point(size= 3) + geom_point(aes(size= new_df$size)) + 
         scale_color_manual(values= c("red", "NavyBlue", "green")) + 
  labs(size= "1", x = "X coords", y = "Y coords",
       title = "Features for KNN", vjust=-10,
       colour = "Class Labels") +  # change the label for legend by variable name in aes()
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, vjust=1),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16), 
        legend.position="bottom", legend.direction = "vertical", #change location and direction of legend
        legend.text = element_text(colour="blue", size = 16, face = "bold")) +  #change style for legend text
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18)) +
  scale_size(guide= "none")
```

[image]

Comment: I am seeking a way to do this with the addition another `geom_point()`. I could have merged the data.frames already, but I'm trying to determine how to do it with an additional element. Thanks for the thought, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. If you want to draw ggplot figures in the way you describe, you could do that. The reason why you were missing navy blue is that you did not put colour in aes() for `test_point`. I created a new column called `hue` using `transform()`. Then, I added the `scale_color_manual()` part to arrange the legend.

```
test_point <- transform(test_point, hue = "Navy blue")

ggplot(data = train1) +
aes(X, Y, colour = cl) +
geom_point(size = 3) +
geom_point(data = test_point, aes(X, Y, colour = hue), size = 4) +
labs(size= "1", x = "X coords", y = "Y coords",
     title = "Features for KNN", vjust=-10,
     colour = "Class Labels") +  # change the label for legend by variable name in aes()
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, vjust=1),
      axis.title=element_text(size=16), 
      legend.position="bottom", legend.direction = "vertical", #change location and direction of legend
      legend.text = element_text(colour="blue", size = 16, face = "bold")) +  #change style for legend text
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18)) +
scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "green", "navy blue"), 
                   name="Class labels",
                   breaks = c("A", "B", "Navy blue"),
                   labels=c("A", "B", "Navy blue"))
```

[image]